# Problem with installing Solana CLI on Windows 11

Tags: cli, solana-cli, windows

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>curl https://release.solana.com/v1.10.32/solana-install-init-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.exe --output C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe --create-dirs
% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current
Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 0
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to verify the revocation for the certificate.
```

I enter a command to install Solana CLI, it gives this error. I run cmd as an administrator, only the solana-install-tmp folder is created, but empty.
Tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running through a proxy. If this is intentional, you can try below to work around it. If it is not, you may want to look into that.
Add:

```
--ssl-no-revoke
```

Docs:
https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--ssl-no-revoke